# Search ldap for a value when I don't know the attribute

Tags: ldap

I can search for a string in a cn
(cn=*trademark*)

Works, makes sense.

My problem is that I am working with a large ldap that I am not familiar, in addition to being new at ldap in general.
I know that a certain string exists as a value, my problem is that I have no idea in which attribute.

Is there a way to ask ldap to return all attributes that contain a certain value?

Something like:
(*=*trademark*)
ie: give me all entries that contain trademark in their value?